# Prestashop preg_match cleanNonUnicodeSupport

Tags: php, preg-match, prestashop

This is a piece of code of prestashop classes/validate.php:

```
  public static function isReference($reference)
    {
        return preg_match(Tools::cleanNonUnicodeSupport('/^[^<>;={}]*$/u'), $reference);
```

This will check it the value is reference or not. Which way does it work, shall there between ' ' quotes be the characters which ARE allowed to go through or the characters which are NOT allowed through? When I left it empty '', nothing went through, but I need to allow anything through.

How to modify this so the reference could be anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be sure to match anything, you can use `[\s\S]`:

```
preg_match(Tools::cleanNonUnicodeSupport('/^[\s\S]*$/u'), $reference);
```

this will match **0** or more any character.
or

```
preg_match(Tools::cleanNonUnicodeSupport('/^[\s\S]+$/u'), $reference);
```

this will match **1** or more any character.